# css list drop down with categories

Tags: html, css

I have this code for my menu. It's a dropdown for my main menu. I want to have categories (all set to 150px witdh), and below them, links with products. All of this have to fit in lets say 300px height and the flow to be vertical until these 300px are filled. And if exceeds this height, the next ul to be shown in second column, then third... until there are categories.

```
<ul id="dropdown">
<li>Cat 1
    <ul>
        <li>Product 1</li>
        <li>Product 2</li>
        <li>Product 3</li>
        <li>Product 4</li>
        <li>Product 5</li>
        <li>Product 6</li>
        <li>Product 7</li>
        <li>Product 8</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Cat 2
    <ul>
        <li>Product 1</li>
        <li>Product 2</li>
        <li>Product 3</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Cat 3
    <ul>
        <li>Product 1</li>
        <li>Product 2</li>
        <li>Product 3</li>
        <li>Product 4</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Cat 4
    <ul>
        <li>Product 1</li>
        <li>Product 2</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Cat 5

</li>
<li>Cat 6
    <ul>
        <li>Product 1</li>
        <li>Product 2</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

The problem is that if I set #dropdown{height:300px;}, the main ul is set to this height, but the inner items are going off the ul and not going on second column. And if I set #dropdown li{float:left;}, the items are showing in rows, not in columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try using child selector

```
#dropdown > li{float:left;}
```

(instead of descendant selector `#dropdown li{float:left;}`)

Moreover, note that child selectors are faster.

Answer (score 0):

You might want `#dropdown > li{float:left;}` which will only apply float left to `li` elements that are direct decedents of the `#dropdown` `ul`.

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qPAms/1) the look you are after?

Comment: Not exactly. If "cat1" is filling the vertical space, then Cat3 must be below Cat2, and Cat4, Cat5 and Cat6 must be all in 3rd column.

Comment: Didn't worked as I expected. Here's a link http://jsfiddle.net/ivanmilanov/HLjEC/

Comment: Check out this article from alistapart http://alistapart.com/article/multicolumnlists

Answer (score 0):

You can try : 
    #dropdown > li { 
        float: left;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }

That way you select only the main categories to be one next to each other with their sublists below them. The margin is important, otherwise the float destroys the normal flow of the elements and they stack too close to each other! :) Hope I've helped.